# image to osd tesseract error using python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I m trying to use image_to_osd function of tesseract but I got this error for python 3.6, but when I test the same script in an other environment with python 3.8 it works !!, is there any configuration for python 3.6 or anything to do ?

`angle_rotated_image = re.search('(?<=Rotate: )\d+',pytesseract.image_to_osd(rotated)).group(0)`

error:

```
     angle_rotated_image = re.search('(?<=Rotate: )\d+',pytesseract.image_to_osd(rotated)).group(0)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 543, in image_to_osd
    }[output_type]()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 542, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 287, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 263, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v5.0.0.20190623 with Leptonica Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Estimating resolution as 163 Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Too few characters. Skipping this page Error during processing.')
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? I'm running into the same issue on Python 3.6.5. I haven't tried it on other versions of Python.

Comment: Indeed no, but what I did is that I used python 3.8 then I built an exe to run it in my environment which contains python 3.6 !!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to determine rotation of a given document and trying to use pytesseract's `image_to_osd()`. It was working fine for me on MacOS with tesseract 4.1.1, but it wouldn't work on Windows with tesseract 5.0.0-alpha. After reading through many threads on the topic related to the OP's error and trying various things like passing `--dpi` and `-c min_chararacters_to_try=` with no success, I finally tried using a different version of tesseract on Windows, which finally solved my problem.

Status of `image_to_osd()`:

- (PASS) OS `MacOS`; tesseract `4.1.1`; pytesseract `0.3.0`; Python `3.6.5`
- (PASS) OS `Windows`; tesseract `4.1.0`; pytesseract `0.3.0`; Python `3.6.5`
- (FAIL) OS `Windows`; tesseract `5.0.0`; pytesseract `0.3.0`; Python `3.6.5`

I think pytesseract `0.3.7` will probably work too, but I didn't test it.

Note that you can still get OP's error with this, but from what I tested it's much more reasonable now, e.g., with blank pages.